# How to convert date time from one time zone to another time zone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

The records are getting saved according to time zone of US but if I want to show the same record back to user it should convert the server date time with(US Time Zone) to user's date time with user's Time Zone

Comment: Oi! Java and Javascript are two entirely different stuff!

Answer (score 13):

If you type in google "Java date change timezone" or "Javascript date change timezone". You will have one of your results:

In Java (source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/417443/java/java/Convert-Date-one-timezone-another )

```
Date date = new Date();  

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");  
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));  

// Prints the date in the CET timezone  
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));  

// Set the formatter to use a different timezone  
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));  

// Prints the date in the IST timezone  
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Javascript (source: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329 )

```
// function to calculate local time
// in a different city
// given the city's UTC offset
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

}

// get Bombay time
alert(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5'));
```

Answer (score 12):

## java.time

The old date-time classes are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

Use modern classes: the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Find back-ports [for earlier Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [for Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/coordinated_Universal_Time?ia=about).

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Never use the 3-4 letter zone abbreviations such as `EST` or `IST`. They are neither standardized nor unique(!). Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), built in a `continent/region` format such as [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata), `Pacific/Auckland`, [`America/Los_Angeles`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Los_Angeles).

```
ZoneId zoneId_Montreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Montreal = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId_Montreal );
```

Apply a different time zone to generate another `ZonedDateTime` adjusted to that time zone. Call [`withZoneSameInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-).

```
ZoneId zoneId_Paris = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ); // Or "Asia/Kolkata", etc.
ZonedDateTime zdt_Paris = zdt_Montreal.withZoneSameInstant( zoneId_Paris );
```

If you want to go back to [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/coordinated_Universal_Time?ia=about), ask for an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = zdt_Paris.toInstant();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeZone fromTimezone =TimeZone.getTimeZone(from);
TimeZone toTimezone=TimeZone.getTimeZone(to);

long fromOffset = fromTimezone.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
long toOffset = toTimezone.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

long convertedTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - (fromOffset - toOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Convert date from one zone to another
/* 
$zone_from='Asia/Kolkata';

$zone_to='America/Phoenix';

date_default_timezone_set($zone_from);

$convert_date="2016-02-26 10:35:00";

echo $finalDate=zone_conversion_date($convert_date, $zone_from, $zone_to);

*/

function zone_conversion_date($time, $cur_zone, $req_zone)
{   
    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
    $gmt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    date_default_timezone_set($cur_zone);
    $local = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    date_default_timezone_set($req_zone);
    $required = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    /* return $required; */
    $diff1 = (strtotime($gmt) - strtotime($local));
    $diff2 = (strtotime($required) - strtotime($gmt));

    $date = new DateTime($time);
    $date->modify("+$diff1 seconds");
    $date->modify("+$diff2 seconds");

    return $timestamp = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

Comment: Question is asked for Java

Answer (score 0):

**Code To Get Berlin Time and Convert it into UTC Time**

```
Calendar sc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
            String strt = null;
            SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");    
            sf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));    
            sc.set(sc.get(Calendar.YEAR),sc.get(Calendar.MONTH),  sc.get(Calendar.DATE),sc.get(Calendar.HOUR) , sc.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            strt = sf.format(sc.getTime());
            System.out.println("Start :"+strt);
```